# What function can I pass to determine the point score in Excel?

Tags: excel, ms-office

I am trying to calculate the point score for which matches the findings column from the data. There are many different sections since there are different categories within the data. What kind of forumla could I use to determine the score based on the different categories? I considered use vlookup but that only works for the first section of the point data.

The objective is to return either 0,1 or 2 based on the category of the data such as media and the finding values

[Excel Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tftqO.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a combination of INDEX, MATCH and OFFSET, with a helper row:

[image]

For formula I'm using there is as follows:

```
=INDEX(OFFSET(INDEX($A$2:$A$12,MATCH(C18,$A$2:$A$12,0)),3,1,1,3),MATCH(B18,OFFSET(INDEX($A$2:$A$12,MATCH(C18,$A$2:$A$12,0)),2,1,1,3),1))
```

`OFFSET(INDEX($A$2:$A$12,MATCH(C18,$A$2:$A$12,0)),3,1,1,3)` this part gives the range for points matching the category. I use something similar to get the range matching the points.

First, `INDEX` and `MATCH` gives the cell containing the category. I use `OFFSET` to move that reference 3 cells down, 1 cell right, keep the height and increase the width to 3. For instance, in D2, INDEX and MATCH gives me cell A7. Offsetting that using the values I mentioned earlier means that the result of offset will be the range B10:D10.

Using the same logic, I get the range B9:D9. From that range, I use `MATCH` to get the highest column in which the value in range B9:D9 is smaller than the listing value, in this case the value 100 is the largest value that is smaller than 165, so I get the result 3 from `MATCH`. This fed into `INDEX` gives the corresponding points.

---

But you can do without `OFFSET` if you can picture the different arrays in your head using only `INDEX` and `MATCH`:

```
=INDEX($B$5:$D$15,MATCH(C18,$A$2:$A$12,0),MATCH(B18,INDEX($B$4:$D$14,MATCH(C18,$A$2:$A$12,0),0),1))
```

Comment: What are the values underneath each range? Whats their purpose

Comment: @DaddyProgrammer `MATCH` cannot do an approximate match if the values are text (because it will perform a math comparison). The values I inserted are numeric and are the lower bounds of each tier's point range.

Comment: Ahhh, Thansk a bunch for the help :)